# time() ok when debugging (JTAG), not-ok when running on-chip. How to time with an embedded proc?

Tags: c, time, arm, benchmarking, processor

I'm "playing" with the rm48 board (Texas Instrument RM48L952, ARM CORTEX-R4F), and i want to time a loop (for instance).

```
char message[20];
int temp=0;
time_t start, end, elapsed; 
sciInit();  

start = time(NULL);
  for(temp=0;temp<0xAAAAAAA;temp++);
end = time(NULL);
elapsed=end-start;
snprintf(message,20,"Duree = %f \r\n",(double)elapsed);
sciSend(scilinREG,20,(unsigned char *)message);
```

when i'm running the program with the JTAG link and CodeComposerStudio (eclipse-like for C), the display is correct (~4s). But when i'm running the program on-chip (stand alone), the display is incorrect (~637488s) and the same whatever the delay is!

SO, why? I presume the time couting depend on the system... 
How to time (benchmark program) on an embedded processor?

Comment: Seems unlikely that for() loop could ever compile. And, are you missing a semi-colon after the for? Makes it much harder to guess what could be wrong if this isn't the real code. :-)

Comment: I missed when I wrote "// the loop" for this post :-P

Comment: Yeah, still couldn't possibly compile. Are you unable to cut/paste from the actual source code?

Comment: yes, it's what i did, i just add a comment (erasing the semilicon by mistake).
But it's not a problem of compilation i presume, since the program runs in debug mode.

Comment: @RollingPierre Your `for` loop is completely messed up, how many semicolons are in there? *Please* copy actual code, don't re-type it.

Comment: done.
i just erase the conditional toggling LED.

Comment: You need to verify that the non-debugging build isn't optimized so that the empty loop goes away. You can do this by reading the generated assembly, for instance.

Comment: I changed the loop : `for(temp=0;temp<0xAAAAAAA;temp++) {i++; if (i==0x5555555) sciSend(scilinREG,10,(unsigned char *)"\r\nMOITIE\r\n");  }` 
Same problem : incorrect returns.
I tested 3 on-chip-runs : 
first result = 63488.00
second : 4160749568.00
third : 0.000 (maybe due to a rollover?)
while the debugging tests all returns the correct 57.00 secondes.

Comment: You did include `time.h`? Also I wonder how you managed to get `Duree = 4160749568.00\n\r\0` as a result with using a 20 character wide buffer?

Comment: yep time.h is included, and the exact result is "Duree = 4160749568."

Comment: thanks for your comments. i'm going to use in-built timer (see my answer to this post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ARM's PDF about [Dhrystone Benchmarking for ARM
Cortex Processors](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0273a/ar01s03s01.html) :

> Most modern ARM processors include performance counters. They can be
>   programmed to count the number of processor cycles, which can be used
>   to accurately compute the elapsed time. The clock() function must be
>   retargeted to use this feature. [...]
>   In the absence of performance counters and a retargeted clock() function, the semihosted 
>   clock() function from the standard C library is used. A debugger capable of supporting
>   semihosting, such as the ARM RealView Debugger (RVD) or DS-5 Debugger
>   must be connected.

Then, I think clock() won't run on-chip. I'm going to use the hardware timers.
What do you think about that? Can I use clock() on-chip? And why did it returns such strange duration (63488 etc)?

Answer (score 1):

what is the frequency of the clock that your are using?.have you enabled any interrupts?if so then your program might be getting interrupted and jumping to ISR often and thus increasing the time for looping..sorry i dont have the privilege to comment.
also if u want to time the cycles its better to use the in-built timer.

Comment: Yes I have enabled interrupts, but the program doesn't run longer on-chip than debugging. The frequency is 160MHz.
The problem is the displayed result, not the duration.

Comment: Wow, i didn't see your edition, yep i agree with you, i'm going to use in-built timer (see my answer to this post).

Comment: are you configuring and stabilizing the clock at the start of the program,if you are not then the clock source to the time() or clock() might not be stabilized by the time you call one of these function. also check TI's RM48L952 errata to make sure of some common problems. clock() can be used but i feel hardware timer will be a better option as u said. also check TI's spnu503a ref manual(osc and pll section). check appendix A in Dhrystone Benchmarking for ARM Cortex Processors.